# How to use web3.py to get data from public chain

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3.py

Platform: Win10+geth1.8.2
I have opened geth to sync block, it's ok to use 'geth attach' directly, but I can't get any return from web3.py. Anyone can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try re-running the code. (If there is some kind of cache clear option in that development environment, use it first).

The line in your console is showing an error on line 33 of `web3test.py`:

```
w3 = Web3(TestRPCProvider())
```

But the `web3test.py` in your screenshot is only 4 lines long, and doesn't include that line of code.